# Why does print 2 cause an error while print "hello" does not?

Tags: function, printing, lua

Ok I have been using Lua for 2 days so far and I have came around several problems! Please Help Me Understand!

1st:

```
>print "hello" 
hello   

>print ("hello")  
hello  

>print (2)  
2  

>print 2 
Error!!
```

Also I have read the documentation and reference manual but for a beginner like me, it is hard to understand the language! I'm still learning from tutorials and a simple book.

Comment: I do not understand your question. I would recommend writing your scripts in a file saving is e.g. as `MyFile.lua` and then running (in the command line) `lua MyFile.lua` in the same directory. It seems like some of your trouble is related to the cli-interpreter. To learn lua, have a look here http://troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/index.htm. This really helped me learn lua back in the day.

Comment: Looks like lua doesn't allow any whitespace between the function name and the opening bracket. But why would you need this?

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Windows . So I can only use CMD as lua interpreter .

Comment: @Picard just to learn the language in depth. But I couldn't understand the reference manual of Lua. Since I'm a beginner.

Comment: If you run the shell simply with `lua` in the cmd, you can just run `lua myfile.lua` with your code in it for the same effect. Add `-i` to be dropped to shell after it finishes. That being said, I'd recommend ZeroBrane for Lua development.

Comment: This message is from Lua 5.1. Later versions have removed this check .

Comment: Lua behaves like this simply because it does. The `print "bar"` or any `foo"bar"` is just a convenience syntax for calling function with a single string argument. It also works only on explicit strings. `a='bar' print a` would result in error as well.

Comment: the second part of your question is off-topic. please remove it. you should not ask for software recommendations here. also, if you have to questions, create two questions...

Answer (score 4):

From the Lua reference manual:
[3.4.10 Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10)

> All argument expressions are evaluated before the call. A call of the
>   form f{fields} is syntactic sugar for f({fields}); that is, the
>   argument list is a single new table. A call of the form f'string' (or
>   f"string" or f[[string]]) is syntactic sugar for f('string'); that is,
>   the argument list is a single literal string.

So `print 2` gives you an error because there is no syntactic sugar for function calls with single numbers as only argument. Why? I don't know. Maybe because you cannot have syntactic sugars for everything :)

Just accept it.

Comment: There's no syntactic sugar for everything because you need a nontrivial percentage of "ungrammatical constructions" to get a reasonable probability of typos being syntax errors, more so as Lua is dynamically typed. Typo-ing `x = 2` or `x, 2` as `x 2` currently gives an error when you load the file, not only when the faulty code eventually runs. And that would be worse than needing parentheses for function calls. (If everything has a meaning, typos just change the meaning (in a way that's probably a bug) and there's no "buffer space" to go "that's nonsense, you certainly meant something else!")